# Filtering Of users in Sudoers File

Tags: linux, unix, sudo, root, sudoers

I have four users :

1. admin1_user
2. admin2_user
3. gen1_user
4. gen2_user

admin1_user & admin2_user are in USER_ALIAS admin. gen1_user & gen2_user are in USER_ALIAS general.

How can I achieve the following criteria so that I can make changes in sudoers file:

- "admin" should have all root access and can access every other user in admin as well as in general.
- "general" should only be able to access users in general and shouldn't be able to access root as well as users in admin.

For eg : from admin1_user ---> he should be able to :

- `sudo su -`
- `sudo su - admin2_user`
- `sudo su - gen1_user` etc.

& from gen1_user ---> he should be able to :

- `sudo su - gen2_user`

  & not allow the following :
- `sudo su -`
- `sudo su - admin1_user`
- `sudo su - admin2_user`

Answer (score 0):

```
admin1_user ALL = ALL
gen1_user ALL = (gen2_user) ALL
```

On the side note this kind of a question might get more attention in [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Can u please provide the exact lines to be written in sudoer file

Comment: I just did that on the above answer.

Comment: I cant access gen2_user from gen1_user using following command :  sudo su - gen2_user .  Can you provide me some alternative

Answer (score 0):

Run [visudo](/questions/tagged/visudo) its pretty self explanatory - or refer this [article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/sudo)